# Make 1 string of multiple ints in Qt

Tags: qt

I want to make a string of 3 ints like this:

```
int ex1= 1

int ex2= 2

int ex3 = 3

"The numbers are: 1, 2, 3"
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
QString result = QString("The numbers are: ") + QString::number(ex1) + QString(", ") + QString::number(ex2) + ... ;
```

See [QString docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

No need to convert explicitly using `QString::number()`.

Using `.arg(x)` needs much less code :

```
QString result = QString("The numbers are: %1, %2, %3").arg(ex1).arg(ex2).arg(ex3);
```